# Running tests in JMeter concurrently

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I want to run the with 100 Users concurrently doing two requests. Between the two requests I have a gaussian ranom timer of 1 second +/- 300 milliseconds. I want to run the test for 10 minutes.
Is my configuration right?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The test runs over 10 Minutes and sends about 12k requests but the results I am getting is seems not to be realistic when considering that 100 Users request information at the same time.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lmjQ.png

Answer (score 0):

1. If your test configuration looks like:

   [image]

   then you don't have the timer "between the two requests", you have the timer **before each request**, if you need to have the timer "between the two requests" - you need to make it the child of the "Request 2". See [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) article for more detailed information
2. 100 users are not concurrently doing 100 requests, each user is:

   - waiting for the time defined by the timer
   - executing request 1
   - waiting for the time defined by the timer
   - executing request 2
   - repeat for 10 minutes

If you need to execute 2 requests at exactly the same time - put them under the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller)

Comment: my ramp-up Period is 0 and Number of threads 100. Does it make a difference?